# Can't use Gradle 2.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I deleted anything related to gradle 1.1 from ~/.gradle and yet I have an error:

```
Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.0. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/alex/Documents/projects/android/MyApp/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip.
```

My settings were (before I had deleted /gradle from the project):

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.0-all.zip
```

Now in File->Settings->Gradle I have this:

```
Use local gradle distribution -> /usr/local/gradle/gradle-2.0
```

which is installed in that folder and has the version of 2.0.

So what's wrong with that?

Here is `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://saturday06.github.io/gradle-android-scala-plugin/repository/snapshot"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath "jp.leafytree.gradle:gradle-android-scala-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Android Gradle plugin is currently not compatible with Gradle 2.0. The latest AOSP branch supports 2.0, so it is likely that the next release of the Gradle plugin will support 2.0 as well ([source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/2.0/adt-dev/3SUeJqu3M9I/txEgq8wNe4YJ)).

I recommend switching back to the wrapper and setting `distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-bin.zip` in your gradle-wrapper.properties.

Alternatively, switch your local Gradle version to 1.10-1.12.